# Card game issues - memory and odd values

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I got the most parts working, including randomizing and shuffling, but when it comes to allocating the right face / suit values, I can't get it right. Also, I'm getting 'Aborted (core dumped)', probably because I have very little idea what I'm doing with `malloc` (If anything at all, in this case).

```
typedef struct cards {
    char suits[4][9], faces[13][6];
    int suit, face, card;
} cards;

const int SHOE_SIZE = DECK_SIZE * numberOfDecks; // user given input, please disregard

cards shoe[SHOE_SIZE];
init_struct(&shoe);

cards *shoe_p = malloc(sizeof(cards) + 1000 * sizeof(int));
shoe_p = shoe;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < SHOE_SIZE; i++) {
    shoe[i].card = i;
    shoe[i].suit = shoe[i].card % 4;  // maybe one of these should be % and another /
    shoe[i].face = shoe[i].card % 13; // but when I try that, I get strings like "ace of ace"
    printf("card #%d = %s of %s\n", i+1, shoe->faces[shoe[i].face], shoe->suits[shoe[i].suit]);
}

free(shoe);
```

The parts of code that I left out are doubtfully sources of the problems described. Please let me know if I should provide more information!

Edit: Additional question; Am I accessing my the struct members 'faces' and 'suits' in a proper manner? To me it would seem so, but then again, I can't see what else should cause the weird output of my string (see comment in code).

Also, can I have SHOE_SIZE as a member of my array, and access it in the same manner(shoe->variable), without having to assign it through the variable SHOE_SIZE first?

Answer (score 4):

```
cards *shoe_p = malloc(sizeof(cards) + 1000 * sizeof(int));
shoe_p = shoe;
```

Here you are leaking memory: `shoe_p` pointed to some mallocated memory, but now you loose that pointer because you re-assign it to a pointer to the first element of `shoe`. I don't think you need these two lines at all.

```
free(shoe);
```

is wrong too: you didn't create `shoe` using `malloc()`, so you don't need to and must not `free()` it.

> probably because I have very little idea what I'm doing with malloc

Right, but don't worry: you can improve your knowledge by reading [this](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html).

Comment: how can I create shoe using malloc?

Comment: @kensing `shoe = malloc(sizeof(cards) * SHOE_SIZE);`

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Thanks, I regularly use that neologism ;)

Comment: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct cards[(unsigned int)SHOE_SIZE]’ from type ‘void *’

I haven't as of yet been able to succeed in using malloc() on anything other than pointers.. where does the (unsigned int) come from?

Comment: @kensing You don't need to define `shoe` as an array. You declare it as a pointer to `card`: `card *shoe = malloc(...);`. Or if you have already defined it as an array, then why would you use `malloc()` at all?

Comment: in a desperate attempt to solve the sturdy segmentation faults I've been having :) however, I'll try playing around with this that you've given me - thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const int SHOE_SIZE = DECK_SIZE * numberOfDecks;
cards shoe[SHOE_SIZE];
```

These lines doesn’t make sense at all. The first line calculates (even as user given input) a constant at runtime. So while compiling its value isn't known yet. But in the next line you are using this unknown number to allocate non-dynamic memory at compilation time. So if you want to do this right, throw the second line away and use `malloc()` (as you did correctly a few lines below). Furthermore, you are discarding this memory with the `shoe_p = shoe;` line. The right way to solve this problem is:

```
...
const int SHOE_SIZE = DECK_SIZE * numberOfDecks;
cards *shoe = malloc(sizeof(cards) + 1000 * sizeof(int));
init_struct(&shoe);

int i;
...
```

And because you're using `malloc()` it is absolutely correct to `free()` it at the and.

Comment: valuable input, however I'm still getting segmentation fault

Comment: As I'm noticing in this very moment, your `malloc()` call makes no sense either. It must be `malloc(sizeof(cards) * 1000);` Or am I understanding something wrong in your source code?

Comment: I was just making sure there was definitely more than enough, but now it's `malloc(sizeof(card) * SHOE_SIZE);`